# getting different value from ASCII code

Tags: c, ascii

I have an application that prompt to user an character from user:

```
char letter;
printf("Letter:\n");
scanf("%s", &letter);
printf("ASCII code = %d\n", letter);
```

The problem is the accent that the user can write. if input is `Á` the code above given ASCII code = -61 then I thought, if I turn it in an positive number, I get `61` that is `A` in ASCII. `printf("ASCII code = %d val = %c\n", letter, abs(letter));`

but it does not works as expected, it given `ASCII code = -61 val =`
 instead of  `A` why?

Comment: Are you sure the abs(letter) output "A", i put "="(ascii +61).As the Pochi said, your char is signed char .   use unsigned char letter;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Á` has character code 193 in ASCII.

The range of a `char` is -128 to 127. The range of `unsigned char` is 0 to 255.

The problem with your code is that you're working with a signed char instead of an unsigned char. When you output the signed char, it will sign extend `letter` to an integer and output it. If you use the unsigned variant you'll get the correct output.

Comment: ASCII characters only go up to 127 - there *is* no Á in ASCII (it is codepoint 193 in ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is the format specifier for a C-string, and a character is only big enough to hold an empty C-string. Use `%c`, which is the format specifier for a single character.

Comment: Fixed. :) but how to solve the problem with ASCII code output?